# Is there any way of using the not (^) in regex for multiple characters?

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation

I want to make a Regex pattern that matches all relative paths.

What I want to match:

```
<img src="image.png"
<img src="http_image.png"
```

What I don't want to match:

```
<img src="http://example/image.png"
```

I tried matching with these patterns, but none of them work:

```
\src="[^http://]\
\src="^(http://)\
\src="[^h][^t][^t][^p][^:][^/][^/]\
\src="([^h][^t][^t][^p][^:][^/][^/])\
```

The `src` attribute will always be formatted with double-quotes (`"`), not single-quotes (`'`). It will always contain an "http" source, not "https" or others.

Comment: You are not understanding how the `^` works. It is used to negate characters in a character class. So what `[^http://]` really means is "match any character that's not an `h`, `t`, `p`, `:`, or `/`"

Comment: I know that... But i just gave some examples to help people understand , what i want to do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to solve this is by using negative lookahead assertion:

```
^img src="(?!http:\/\/\S+).*"$
```

[Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/5kLNEmb5nx)

```
^                  : Start anchor
img src="          : Literal img src="
(?!http:\/\/\S+)   : To ensure the string following " is not a URL
.*                 : Anything else is allowed
"                  : Literal "
$                  : End anchor
```

Comment: TYVM! Btw, do you know how to add img src="http://example/image.png" (with brackets) in stackoverflow and make it display as text?